# How to obtain HttpServletRequest in AppservPasswordLoginModule (SSL)

Tags: authentication, glassfish, jaas

In a customized Login Module I've developed for my application server (GlassFish 3.1.2.2), I'm using the following syntax to obtain the HttpServletRequest:

```
PolicyContext.getContext(HttpServletRequest.class.getName())
```

And it works fine.

But now I'm configuring the server to use only HTTPS and the same instruction returns null.
I guess this is a security restriction, but I'm not sure what needs to be changed in order to solve this issue (server.policy?).
To put this under context, I need to record the IP address of all login attempts, valid and invalid, and getting the request in the module seemed the most obvious solution.

Can someone help me to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you directly with your question, but you may want to note that `PolicyContext` is a JACC class. It's spec'ed to work inside JACC policy providers. You may want to look at [an article I wrote](http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.com/2014/03/implementing-container-authorization-in.html) that explains this more in depth.

There is thus no specific guarantee that obtaining the `HttpServletRequest` works from inside a GlassFish proprietary login module, although I indeed have seen people using this more often and it typically works. The fact that it does not work when you switch to https sounds more like a bug or oversight to me than any specific security restriction.

A workaround for you could be to rewrite your login module as a Java EE standard auth module using JASPIC. I've also written [an article](http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.com/2012/11/implementing-container-authentication.html) about that subject which you could use for reference. In JASPIC you explicitly have access to the `HttpServletRequest`.